# Postgresql: how to dynamically set row estimation?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-function

Is it possible to specify the rows count which returns from a function, depending on the function's arguments? Something like this:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION some_func (x int[], OUT xxx int, OUT yyy int)
    RETURNS SETOF record
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS $$
DECLARE
    foo int;
BEGIN
    RETURN query
    SELECT 5, 3;
END;
$$ ROWS array_length(x, 1) * 2; --This doesn't work
```

Comment: I think you need to create a [support function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-optimization.html)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yeah, thanks. It looks like what I want but to complicated for me. So I just add a  limit in the query and the planner now knows how many rows will be returned. Maybe not good solution but works for me.